# Specifying types and patterns using argparse choices

Tags: python, argparse

I have several different input files, saved with case numbers ".1", ".2", etc to differentiate them. I am building a script that operates on these files, and I would like to use argparse to allow the user to specify the particular case number to operate on, or use "_" to specify the last saved case (i.e. the input file with the largest case number). Something like;

```
> ls 
   file.1, file.2, file.3
> my_script.py 2
   (operates on file.2)
> my_script.py _
   (operate on file.3)
```

Is there a way I can specify "any integer" as one choice and "_" as the second choice? Something like;

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('case', choices=[anyint, '_'])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`type`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#type) argument to `add_argument(...)` instead. For example:

```
import os
import argparse

def intOrUnderscore(s):
    if s != '_':
        return int(s)
    cases = (n for n in os.listdir(".") if n.startswith("file."))
    return max(int(c[c.rindex(".")+1:]) for c in cases)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('case', type=intOrUnderscore)

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.case
```

When I run this I get:

```
$ ls
file.1  file.2  file.3  s.py
$ python s.py 2
2
$ python s.py _
3
```

Alternately, you could build the choices list in code:

```
import os
import argparse

cases = [n[n.rindex(".")+1:] for n in os.listdir(".") if n.startswith("file.")]
cases.append("_")
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('case', choices = cases)

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.case
```

Comment: Excellent. I used option #1 (defining intOrUnderscore function) and it works like a charm. Thanks!